# Link to logo within XML layout file

Tags: magento2, xml, paths

I'm getting 404 for my logo in my default.xml

Existing code:

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_src" xsi:type="string">\images\logo-small-730.png</argument>
            <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">Book of Us</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

What is the correct path to use in layout XML files?? in /app/design/frontend/themename/deafult/web/images

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your store uses the theme you mention in your path, the below should work. I have tried the solution below on my Magento 2 local (M2 2.3.3)

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo-small-730.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">Book of Us</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Also, if you need to understand why, you can take a look at the function `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo::_getLogoUrl`